# How to get rows in a column in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to restructure a pandas data frame. Let's say, I have the below data frame;

| uri | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| bbb | 4 | 5 | 6 |

I am trying to restructure as below;

| uri | IDs |
| --- | --- |
| aaa | 1 |
| aaa | 2 |
| aaa | 3 |
| bbb | 4 |
| bbb | 5 |
| bbb | 6 |

I know the transform function but it is not doing what I want. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `stack`:

```
>>> df.set_index('uri').stack().droplevel(1).rename('IDs').reset_index()
   uri  IDs
0  aaa    1
1  aaa    2
2  aaa    3
3  bbb    4
4  bbb    5
5  bbb    6
```